# How to include file from node_modules in laravel (sweetalert2)

Tags: laravel

I am trying to include sweetalert but it's seems like I misunderstood the instructions from the documentations. Currently struggling how to include files from node_modules folder.

In my blade I put script like these:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Swal.fire(
        'The Internet?',
        'That thing is still around?',
        'question'
    )
});
```

---

I tried all these methods but none works:

**Method (1)** - adding these codes in my app.js file (base from [sweetalert doc](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download))

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js'
import 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss'
```

**Method (2)** - adding these codes in my app.js file (based from [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix))

```
mix.copy('node_modules\sweetalert2\dist\sweetalert2.js', 'public/js/sweetalert2.js');
mix.copy('node_modules\sweetalert2\dist\sweetalert2.css', 'public/js/sweetalert2.css');
```

*and then,*

```
<link href="{{ asset('js/sweetalert2.js') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/sweetalert2.css') }}"></script>
```

---

It always returns an error from my console

**ReferenceError: mix is not defined**

see full error logs: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jZfR.png)

---

Sorry for my ignorance. Can someone knows how / what is really a proper way of including a file(s) from node_modules?

Comment: Is your browser loading the script file correctly? (See network tb on dev inspector)

Comment: I see this `mix.copy('node_modules/foo/bar.css', 'public/css/bar.css');` and you have this `mix.copy('node_modules\sweetalert2\dist\sweetalert2.js', 'public/js/sweetalert2.js');`, back slashes

Comment: `swal()` function name is lowercase, your error shows you trying to access it as `Swal()` (first letter uppercase). Probably that's the reason.

Comment: @eliassoares the docs says he should call it that way

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen already tried but still not working.

Comment: Did you restart the server after the change?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen and also returning me an error **ReferenceError: mix is not defined**

Comment: is mix installed properly?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I already `npm install` and currently `npm run dev`. And also `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` in my blade. What am I lacking?

Comment: @EliasSoares I already edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need use mix to copy the sweatalert js file to public path

1. Install sweatalert with npm

```
npm install sweetalert2
```

2. You have two different choices in your `app.js` file use

```js
import Swal from 'sweatalert2';
```

OR

```js
var Swal = require('sweatalert2');
```

after that run the below command to compile the js file

```
npm run watch
```

after that append `js` file in `the app layout` after that in each file you can use 
Swal module

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    Swal.fire(
        'The Internet?',
        'That thing is still around?',
        'question'
    )
});
```

but you must do this after the section you import the `app.js` file because before that `Swal` not loaded in your project

Answer (score 2):

1. Install sweet Alert 2 with npm

   ```
   npm install sweetalert2
   ```
2. In your app.js file

   ```
   import swal from 'sweetalert2';
   window.swal = swal;

   const toast = swal.mixin({
   toast: true,
   position: 'top-end',
   showConfirmButton: false,
   timer: 3000
   });
   window.toast = toast;
   ```
3. in your component

   ```
   swal.fire({
              title: 'Are you sure?',
               text: "You won't be able to revert this!" + id,
               type: 'warning',
               showCancelButton: true,
               confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
               cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
               confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
           }).then((result) => {

               // Send request to the server
               if (result.value) {

                   axios.delete("api/category/" + id).then(() => {

                      toast.fire({
                           type: 'success',
                           title: 'Deleted successfully'
                       });

                   }).catch(() => {
                       toast.fire({
                           type: 'error',
                           title: 'Error Occurred..!'
                       })
                   });

               }
           })
   ```
4. run npm run dev

   ```
   npm run dev
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Put `const mix = require('laravel-mix');` in webpack at first line. at try to re run webpack.

Comment: already put it. but still not working can you check my full error logs :). Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put of time but try in bootstrap.js:

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
```

then in the same file inside the try section:

```
window.Swal = require('sweetalert2');
```